# DotNetNuke missing menu navigation for FireFox version 17

Tags: dotnetnuke

We have a DotNetNuke app with a DNN Menu.

Recently, after updating to FireFox version 17 we found that the whole DNN Navigation Menu is invisible. In other browsers it is fine, and it also works fine in FireFox 16 and earlier versions.

Does this have anything to do with the browser settings?

Comment: check if there are any javascript errors, if any paste here

Comment: I don't find  any JS errors, I saw using FF debugger

Answer (score 1):

Firefox changed their user agent string. Here's the fix: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/Question/2733/Firefox17-Bug-How-to-change-User-Agent-String.aspx

Comment: Could you add the basics of the solution on the linked page? That way if the [link rots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) this answer will still help future visitors.

Comment: This link no longer goes to a how-to.

Answer (score 1):

We found a solution that may help.  Our menu was displaying, but expanded the entire thing out as an unordered list.  We're on DNN 5.6.0 and using the DNNMenuNavigationProvider.

We installed the DDRMenuNavigationProvider here:
http://dnnddrmenu.codeplex.com/

With detailed instructions here:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DDRMenu-user-guide.aspx

We simply then went into the skins and updated the same dnn:NAV controls to use the ProviderName="DDRMenuNavigationProvider" and the menu came back the way it was, with an extra sliding flyout animation.

Hope that helps.

Update
In addition to updating the navigation provider, and the user agent as described above, we also updated the \js\ClientAPICaps.config file based on these instructions:
http://support.dotnetnuke.com/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?ID=13964&PROJID=2

We reverted the update for the dnn:NAV controls back to DNNMenuNavigationProvider and everything went back to the way it was operating before.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox released a patch, 17.0.1, which fixed this (for now) for my situation. This bullet item from [the release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/17.0.1/releasenotes/) is about this issue:

> - 17.0.1: Reverted user agent change causing some website incompatibilities.